# How do I debug a common DLL project?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

As the question title suggests, I have two solutions: one for an ASP.NET site and another for DLL projects.

When I debug the site, I want to stop at breakpoints in the DLLs.

How can I accomplish that without "stepping into" the code there from the *.pdb files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the common dll's project to your site's solution, change the reference from a dll reference to a project reference and you can easily step into the common dll's code and breakpoints in both projects will be hit.

Alternatively you can keep the dll reference, and open the a code file that is compiled into dll in the project that uses it. You can then set a breakpoint in this code and step through it, but this way you lose a lot of the metadata which makes debugging harder.

Comment: Yes, thank you but I know it already. I don't want to step into... I want to stop at breakpoints that are located within the DLLs.